# Objective-c power operator not clear

Tags: objective-c, math

Im working on a small calculation app and I'm using a formula I created in PHP and now trying to translate to Objective-C however, the power operator is not clear to me.

Im looking at the following code:

```
float value = ((((x)*i)/12)/(1-(1+i/12)^-((x*12))))-i;
```

The power operator is non existent in Objective-C.

How should I apply the power operator in Objective-C and could some assist me by telling me where it should be?

Comment: "^" in PHP and other C-based languages is actually the XOR operator. And there is no power operator in PHP (you need to use `pow` function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Too many parentheses! You don't need parentheses around `x` or `(x*12)`, for instance.)

There is no power operator. The standard function `powf()` will do the job, however (`pow()` if you wanted a `double` result):

```
float value = x * i / 12 / (1 - powf(1 + i / 12, -12 * x)) - i;
```

Comment: Somehow my function still doesnt work the way the PHP Variant is: PHP One: $aflossing = $annuiteit - (((($schuldBeginPeriode)*$renteperjaar)/12)/(1-(1+$renteperjaar/12)^-(($looptijdinmaanden*12))))-$rente; The Objective-c one: aflossing = annuiteit - (schuldBeginPeriode * renteperjaar / 12 / (1 - powf(1 + renteperjaar / 12, -12 * looptijdinmaanden))) - rente; Any idea?

Comment: I seriuosly lolled at `looptijd‌​inmaanden`, whatever it means.

Comment: @BenjaminDeBos - You don't get the same result as in PHP as your PHP (like most PHP) doesn't do what you expect. Try "3.2 ^ 4.2 + 5.2" in PHP and you'll find the answer is 10! It goes as follows: 4.2 + 5.2 => 9.4; 3.2 ^ 9.4 => 3 ^ 9 (^ - xor - takes integers) => 10 (0011 ^ 1001 => 1010).

Comment: @GabrielePetronella it's a Dutch set of words. Without capitalisation ;-) its looptijdInMaanden. Meaning; length in months.

Comment: @BenjamindeBos Dutch is an incredibly appropriate language for matching Objective-C verbosity then ;)

Answer (score 4):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator both in C (and so in Objective-C as well) and [in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

To perform a power operator use the C `pow` (which returns a `double`) or `powf` (which returns a `float`) functions

```
float result = powf(5, 2); // => 25
```

Your expression will then become (stripping away all the redundant parenthesis and leaving some for readability) :

```
float value = (x*i/12) / (1 - powf(1 + i/12, -x*12)) - i;
```